# Far field microphone is required

Tags: audio, microphones

I am looking for Far field microphone technology.

I need line level Output. I **do not** need natural language processing using alexa or anything.

I Just need clean audio out at line level. Looking to make prototype.

Thanks
Sudhanshu Mehta

Comment: You may do better asking this on https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You really need to elaborate your need if you want to get some answers. A "microphone" is an audio input, it makes your question is even more confusing...

Comment: I mean I need far field microphone system. This system must be capable of converting mic level input to Line level output. Requirement is this line level signal must be clean.